# what is the point of using DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR over "/" in php

Tags: php, directory, separator

Why would I choose to use `. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .` instead of `. "/" .` ?

My initial thought was that there could be a different separator instead of a slash, but if I'm designing, say, a Wordpress Plugin, can I not assume that there is always a / separating two folders?

Comment: The forward slash is compatible on all current systems; including Windows. What you definitely need that constant for is *analyzing **system/input** paths*, not for file access itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the application is going to run on a variety of operating systems then the directory won't always be a forward slash. It's a backwards slash on Windows for example.

A similar case is new lines. It's `\n` on *nix, `\r\n` on Windows, etc. That's why there is `PHP_EOL`.