# Uploading file on server

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

previously i was able to do this but suddenly it does not work anymore, i have no idea what i changed or what went wrong, i am simply trying to upload an image to my bluehost sever and this is the error i get:

```
Could not move the file "/tmp/phptcHTsU" to "\uploads\data\users\34/Ns3RJWE8FGZLG2gz.jpg" ()
```

This is my file upload code:

```
if (Input::file('upload')->isValid()) {
    $file = Input::file('upload');
    $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    // Setting allowed file extensions
    $allowed = array('JPG', 'jpg', 'JPEG', 'jpeg', 'GIF', 'gif', 'PNG', 'png', 'BMP', 'bmp');

    if (!in_array($ext, $allowed)) {
        echo "Not Allowed!";
    }

    // Creating image upload path
    $destinationPath = public_path() . sprintf("\\uploads\\data\\users\\%d\\", Auth::user()->getId());
    $realPath = sprintf("uploads/data/users/%d/", Auth::user()->getId());

    if (!file_exists($destinationPath)) {
        mkdir($destinationPath, 0777, true);
    }

    $fileName = str_random(16);
    $image_url = $realPath . '/' . $fileName . '.' . $ext;

    if ($file->move($destinationPath, $fileName . '.' . $ext)) {
        $p->display_pic = $image_url;
    }
}
```

The above file works on my local machine which is windows 8 but not on my Linux VPS server.  I have not run out of disk space.

Comment: Have you run out of file space on the server?

Comment: No i have not, this script works on my local machine (windows 8) but not on my VPS server (linux).

Comment: Maybe it's a permissions issue? Can you confirm that the `uploads`, `data`, `users` and the created `{user_id}` folders have 777 perms?

Comment: No it is not a permission issue, all those folders have 0777 permissions, actually struggled with that before where i was getting "permission denied" whenever i try to move a file but i finally got it fixed.

Comment: Windows do use \ when, as the error is clearly showing, linux is using / for folders delimiters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the directory separator not being the same on the two OS (Linux and Windows).

You really should use the constant [`DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047516/what-is-the-point-of-using-directory-separator-over-in-php) instead.

```
$destinationPath = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
                   "uploads" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
                   "data" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
                   "users" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .
                   Auth::user()->getId() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Comment: Okay after doing this i get "mkdir(): Permission denied " which is weird because the folder permission is set to 0777

Comment: Mhm by the look of your error your  `public_path` is getting you nothing : "\uploads\data\users\34/Ns3RJWE8FGZLG2gz.jpg" so that means he will try to create a upload folder at the root of your server

Comment: Oh okay, wow so how do i fix this and why is my public_path not giving me anything?

Comment: I'm not an expert at laravel, but maybe this may be of any help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321052/public-path-laravel-not-working